# Double Dispatch, Multiple Inheritance, and Shared Pointers

Tags: c++, design-patterns, shared-ptr

Is the following code the proper usage of `shared_from_this` - in the context of (multiple inheritance and proper reference counts)? The code is and implementation of the double dispatch visitor pattern where the interface accepts a shared pointer.

```
class EventIf;
typedef std::shared_ptr<EventIf> EventIfPtr;

class DispatchIF;
typedef std::shared_ptr<DispatchIF> DispatchIFPtr;

class EventOne;
typedef std::shared_ptr<EventOne> EventOnePtr;

class EventTwo;
typedef std::shared_ptr<EventTwo> EventTwoPtr;

class DispatchIF
{
    public:
        Dispatch(EventOnePtr pEvent){ std::cout << pEvent->GetType(); }
        Dispatch(EventTwoPtr pEvent){ std::cout << pEvent->GetType() << pEvent->foo; }
};

class EventIf
{
    public:
        EventIf(theType) : type(theType) {}
        virtual ~EventIf(){}
        int GetType(){ return type; }
        virtual void Accept(DispatchIFPtr pDispatcher) = 0;

    protected:
        int type;
};

cass EventOne : public EventIf, std::enable_shared_from_this<EventOne>
{
    public:
        EventOne() : EventIf(1) {}
        virtual ~EventOne(){}
        virtual void Accept(DispatchIFPtr pDispatcher){ pDispatcher->Dispatch(shared_from_this()); }
};

cass EventTwo : public EventIf, std::enable_shared_from_this<EventTwo>
{
    public:
        EventTwo() : EventIf(1) {}
        virtual ~EventTwo(){}
        virtual void Accept(DispatchIFPtr pDispatcher){ pDispatcher->Dispatch(shared_from_this()); }

    public:
        int foo;
};
```

Comment: Does it work correctly and pass all tests?

Comment: Please check. There are some obvious syntax errors.

Comment: This will only work if you call `Accept` on instances of `EventOne` / `EventTwo` that are already shared - E.g. `EventTwo ev; ev.Accept(dispatcher);` won't work (UB before c++17, exceptions since c++17).

Comment: @Holt - while they will likely be created as shared pointers, how would I deal w/ the issue you've mentioned?

Comment: @pyInTheSky You can make the constructor privates, and make a friend factory that only returns `shared_ptr`. I can't say much, it depends on your use case...

Comment: Why do you pass `shared_ptr` in the first place ? You don't transfer ownership.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm not sure if the interface accepting the event, will store the event, and the event is constructed as a shared pointer, so I do want the reference count to go up -- i think.

Comment: I guess I should ask -- is shared_from_this() even appropriate -- or is there a better/different way to pass `this` to a function which takes a sharedptr?

Comment: Your `DispatchIF` doesn't. and if it really need, it can do the `shared_from_this` itself. From your example you should not have any `share_ptr` (Whereas `Visitor` might eventually share ownership, your `Accept` doesn't.